# Code that could save data by entering through jframe to database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am making a form based database, the problem is that I cant figure out as how the table of the database will be updated with the data I entered through form .. Here is the code.

```
   public New_Entry() {
    initComponents();
 }

 private void pat_nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
 }                                        

 @SuppressWarnings("UseSpecificCatch")
```

For this is the code string for the update button...... Kindly help me out what to do....???

```
 private void cmd_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con;
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
String user ="root";
String password ="";

con=(javaapplication5.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);


Statement stmt= con.createStatement();

    String Patient_ID=pat_id.getText();
    String name=pat_name.getText();
    String age=pat_age.getText();
    String sex=pat_sex.getText();
    String unit=pat_unit.getText();
    String Diagonisis=diagonisis.getText();
    String DateOfAddmission=DOA.getText();
    String TreatmentPlan=treat_plan.getText();


String sql1 = "Insert into patient   (Patient_ID,Name,Age,Unit,Sex,Diagonsis,DateOfAddmission,Treatment_Plan) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    stmt=con.prepareStatment(sql1);

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
    pat_id.setText("");
    pat_name.setText("");
    pat_age.setText("");
    pat_sex.setText("");
    pat_unit.setText("");
    diagonisis.setText("");
    DOA.setText("");
    treat_plan.setText("");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Record Updated!");
}
     catch(Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());

    }
}                                          

private void pat_ageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void pat_unitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void DOAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void pat_idActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void cmd_exitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void cmd_backActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 Start form = new Start();
 New_Entry.this.setVisible(false);
 form.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void cmd_newformActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    New_Entry frame2 = new New_Entry();
    New_Entry.this.setVisible(false);
    frame2.setVisible(true);
}                                           

private void diagonisisActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Creating a PreparedStatement Object

The following creates a PreparedStatement object that takes two input parameters:

```
String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

### Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters

You must supply values in place of the question mark placeholders (if there are any) before you can execute a PreparedStatement object. Do this by calling one of the setter methods defined in the PreparedStatement class. The following statements supply the two question mark placeholders in the PreparedStatement named updateSales:

```
updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
```

The first argument for each of these setter methods specifies the question mark placeholder. In this example, setInt specifies the first placeholder and setString specifies the second placeholder.
Link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

In your case before you use executUpdate method you will have to supply the values using your string fields, refer Supplying Values of PreparedStatement parameters.

Comment: i still didn't get what to do..!! :(

Comment: In your code for the Update button you want to insert the String parameters for the '?' characters. The Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters section above gives you an example how to do that. 
If you need an answer how to do the entire process (button click event handling, creating a connection etc) Please look at the answer from @Amit Bhati

Answer (score 1):

1) Bind all the values on the JFrame to Java Pojo or class.
See the answer : [Binding of JText fields value to Info Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337986/binding-of-jtext-fields-value-to-info-class)

2) Now bind an action method to the save button, here you can use the class of step 1 to get the values entered through form. Now all you have to do is to create the connection with the DB and insert the data.

Read about Variable binding in swing to get a better idea.